# Is there any linux distribution that comes with python 3?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I would like to know if there is any Linux distribution where you can easily install and use Python 3. This means a distribution that will provide not only Python 3 binaries and updates but also python modules.

I know that probably we are not going to see any python 3 as the default python interpretor so soon but at least I would like to see latest 2.x as default (2.6+) one and the alternative one already installed.

Probably it is a question between major distributions: Ubuntu, Fedora or Suse?

Comment: Any of them! I've been using Py3k on Ubuntu for quite a while.

Comment: I'm not going to bother creating another answer. Pretty much, all distros of linux have a repository with Python (Even mac has it installed by default). If you're running Ubuntu or Linux Mint, open synaptic package manager and search for python. You should be able to install versions 2.6-3.1. For any/all third party libraries look them up on PYPI (Python Package Index).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 comes by default w/ Python 2.6.5, but the following python 3 packages are in the standard repositories as well:

```
python3                 python3.1-minimal       python3-dev
python3.0               python3.1-profiler      python3-doc
python3.1               python3.1-tk            python3-examples
python3.1-celementtree  python3.1-wsgiref       python3-gdbm
python3.1-cjkcodecs     python3.2               python3-gdbm-dbg
python3.1-ctypes        python3-all             python3-minimal
python3.1-dbg           python3-all-dbg         python3-pkg-resources
python3.1-dev           python3-all-dev         python3-profiler
python3.1-doc           python3-bsddb           python3-setuptools
python3.1-elementtree   python3-bsddb3          python3-tk
python3.1-examples      python3-bsddb3-dbg      python3-tk-dbg
python3.1-gdbm          python3-dbg
```

update:
for *ubuntu 11.04 the list is (as expected) a bit longer) note that I left out the python3.1- and python3.2- prefixed packages):

```
python3-all                 python3-examples            python3-pkg-resources
python3-all-dbg             python3-gdbm                python3-profiler
python3-all-dev             python3-gdbm-dbg            python3-pygments
python3-apt                 python3-gearman.libgearman  python3-pyudev
python3-apt-dbg             python3-httplib2            python3-serial
python3-beaker              python3-ipaddr              python3-setuptools
python3-bsddb3              python3-jinja2              python3-sip
python3-bsddb3-dbg          python3-jinja2-dbg          python3-sip-dbg
python3-cxx                 python3-lxml                python3-sip-dev
python3-cxx-dev             python3-lxml-dbg            python3-sqlalchemy
python3-dbg                 python3-mako                python3-tk
python3-dev                 python3-markupsafe          python3-tk-dbg
python3-distutils-extra     python3-markupsafe-dbg      python3-yaml
python3-dns                 python3-minimal             python3-yaml-dbg
python3-doc                 python3-objgraph            python3-zope.fixers
```

UPDATE (2013-03-21):
The current version of *buntu (12.10) already has fairly many Python 3 packages available (>200; too many to list). Prominent exceptions include python3-django and python3-matplotlib (though the latter will be included in 13.04 Raring Ringtail). If you require a package not yet in the package manager but already ported, 12.10 includes both pip and easy_install for Python 3.

Comment: So does the few previous Ubuntu versions (but not sure how far back).

Comment: Note that most (all?) of these simply belong to a standard python distribution. There are almost no additional libraries.

Answer (score 7):

According to [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?pkg=Python&pkgver=3#pkgsearch), the following distributions currently include Python version 3:

- Arch Linux
- ArchBang Linux
- Calculate Linux
- CTKArch
- FreeBSD
- Frugalware Linux: current, 1.5
- Funtoo Linux
- Gentoo Linux
- KahelOS
- Litrix Linux
- NetBSD
- PapugLinux
- Source Mage GNU/Linux
- Toorox
- UTUTO

Answer (score 5):

Fedora, starting with [13](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Python3F13), allows python3 to be installed in parallel with python2 and it includes some of the more popular python3 modules.

Answer (score 5):

All of them have the repositories, but if you care for one that has python3 as default, I only know of ArchLinux.

Answer (score 2):

I think most distros have it. Debian has it so all derived distros (Ubuntu et. all) do. Fedora as well. It's just that it's not used for the standard system utilities so just typing `python` will give you a 2.x interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Gentoo has Python3 (I have 2.6.4-r1 and 3.1.2-r3 installed, 2.6 being the default). A quick search reveals that ebuilds of python libraries tested on both 2.x and 3.x have already been built for both versions on my machine (thank God for `python-updater`, obviously).

Gentoo + Python developing is a very nice combination (if you do like the way Gentoo works, that is).